# Can I get the TangoPose relative to gravity?

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm using Tango motion tracking and it is very easy to get the pose of the device relative to the TANGO_START_OF_SERVICE.  For the translation that works fine for me, but I'd like my orientation to be aligned with gravity, so that the yaw and roll angles are aligned with gravity rather than with the arbitrary position at which the Tango service started.  I'm fine with an arbitrary azimuth angle.

I can do this by using the accelerometer data to get the absolute orientation at one point in time and then use that going forward, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

I think the Z axis of TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH frame is always aligned with gravity.